# Format keywords inside section and subsection

Tags: sectioning, formatting, tags

**Problem:**

Google is not being helpful so I turn to those better than Google. The problem is that I want to create a "function" that reads all `\section` and `\subsection` and if the function finds a pattern like `<keyword>` then it should be formatted with `\texttt{}`.

**For instance:**

```
\section{Headline <keyword>}
```

**Should output as if it was:**

```
\section{Headline \texttt{<keyword>}}
```

**Delimitation:**

This should only apply to `\section` and `\subsection`.

**Minimal Working Example (MWE):**

I usually post a MWE but this time I could not find any guide that details how to create such a function. I would appreciate if someone could share documentation so I could enlighten myself.

**Update (section and subsection code from .cls):**

```
%
% Section headings
%
\raggedbottomsection
%
\setsecindent{0pt}
\setbeforesecskip{-8mm plus -1mm minus -1mm}
\setaftersecskip{1.411mm plus 0.2mm minus 0.2mm}
\setsecnumformat{\csname the#1\endcsname\hspace*{0.5em}}
\setsecheadstyle{\rmfamily\mdseries\fontsize{14}{14}\selectfont\raggedright\color{\colsection}}
%
\setsubsecindent{0pt}
\setbeforesubsecskip{-24pt plus -3pt minus -2pt}
\setaftersubsecskip{4pt plus 0pt}
\setsubsecheadstyle{\sffamily\bfseries\boldmath\fontsize{9.5}{14}\selectfont\raggedright\color{\colsubsection}\MakeUppercase}
%
```

Comment: To me this sounds more like a custom defined `\keyword` or a search-and-replace instead of modifying the `\section` and `\subsection` commands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No change to the default code and no category code change either.

The argument (or arguments in case of `\section[x]{y}`) are massaged looking for `<(any tokens)>` (lazy search) and substituting it with `\texttt{<(any tokens)>}`, then passed to the original `\section` or `\subsection` commands.

If you plan to use the double optional argument provided by `memoir`, some changes are needed in the scanning of the optional arguments.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse,l3regex}
\usepackage{color}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_eq:NN \latexsection \section
\cs_set_eq:NN \latexsubsection \subsection

\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{}
 {
  \genericsection{\latexsection}
 }
\RenewDocumentCommand{\subsection}{}
 {
  \genericsection{\latexsubsection}
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\genericsection}{msom}
 {
  \IfValueT{#3}
   {
    \kexx_section_keyword:Nn \l_kexx_section_texto_tl { #3 }
   }
  \kexx_section_keyword:Nn \l_kexx_section_textm_tl { #4 }
  \IfBooleanTF{#2}
   {
    #1*{\l_kexx_section_textm_tl}
   }
   {
    \IfValueTF{#3}
     {
      #1[ \l_kexx_section_texto_tl ]{ \l_kexx_section_textm_tl }
     }
     {
      #1{ \l_kexx_section_textm_tl }
     }
   }
 }

\tl_new:N \l_kexx_section_textm_tl
\tl_new:N \l_kexx_section_texto_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \kexx_section_keyword:Nn
 {
  \tl_set:Nn #1 { #2 }
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { (\<.*?\>) } { \c{texttt}\cB\{\1\cE\} } #1
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\section{Headline <keyword> \textcolor{red}{\itshape{this}}}

\subsection{Headline  <keyword>}

\subsection{Headline \textcolor{red}{<keyword>}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In order to accommodate the double optional argument of `memoir`, some more work is needed:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{xparse,l3regex}
\usepackage{color}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_eq:NN \memoirsection \section
\cs_set_eq:NN \memoirsubsection \subsection

\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{}
 {
  \genericsection{\memoirsection}
 }
\RenewDocumentCommand{\subsection}{}
 {
  \genericsection{\memoirsubsection}
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\genericsection}{msoom}
 {
  \IfValueTF{#4}
   {
    \kexx_section_keyword:Nn \l_kexx_section_textob_tl { #4 }
    \kexx_section_keyword:Nn \l_kexx_section_textoa_tl { #3 }
   }
   {
    \IfValueT{#3}
     {
      \kexx_section_keyword:Nn \l_kexx_section_textoa_tl { #3 }
     }
   }
  \kexx_section_keyword:Nn \l_kexx_section_textm_tl { #5 }
  \IfBooleanTF{#2}
   {
    #1*{\l_kexx_section_textm_tl}
   }
   {
    \IfValueTF{#4}
     {
      #1[ \l_kexx_section_textoa_tl ][ \l_kexx_section_textob_tl ]{ \l_kexx_section_textm_tl }
     }
     {
      \IfValueTF{#3}
       {
        #1[ \l_kexx_section_textoa_tl ]{ \l_kexx_section_textm_tl }
       }
       {
        #1{ \l_kexx_section_textm_tl }
       }
     }
   }
 }

\tl_new:N \l_kexx_section_textm_tl
\tl_new:N \l_kexx_section_textoa_tl
\tl_new:N \l_kexx_section_textob_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \kexx_section_keyword:Nn
 {
  \tl_set:Nn #1 { #2 }
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { (\<.*?\>) } { \c{texttt}\cB\{\1\cE\} } #1
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\section{Headline <keyword> \textcolor{red}{\itshape{this}}}

\subsection{Headline  <keyword>}

\subsection[<key>][aaa<key>]{Headline \textcolor{red}{<keyword>}}

\end{document}
```

More complicated is getting uppercase titles, but it's possible.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{xparse,l3regex}
\usepackage{color}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_eq:NN \memoirchapter \chapter
\cs_set_eq:NN \memoirsection \section
\cs_set_eq:NN \memoirsubsection \subsection

\tl_put_right:Nn \l_tl_case_change_exclude_tl { \textttnocase }

\RenewDocumentCommand{\chapter}{}
 {
  \genericsection{\use:n}{\memoirchapter}
 }
\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{}
 {
  \genericsection{\use:n}{\memoirsection}
 }
\RenewDocumentCommand{\subsection}{}
 {
  \genericsection{\tl_upper_case:n}{\memoirsubsection}
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\genericsection}{mmsoom}
 {
  \IfValueTF{#5}
   {
    \kexx_section_keyword:Nn \l_kexx_section_textob_tl { #5 }
    \kexx_section_keyword:Nn \l_kexx_section_textoa_tl { #4 }
   }
   {
    \IfValueT{#4}
     {
      \kexx_section_keyword:Nn \l_kexx_section_textoa_tl { #4 }
     }
   }
  \kexx_section_keyword:Nn \l_kexx_section_textm_tl { #6 }
  \IfBooleanTF{#3}
   {
    \use:x
     {
      \exp_not:N #2 * { \exp_not:N #1 {\exp_not:V \l_kexx_section_textm_tl} }
     }
   }
   {
    \IfValueTF{#5}
     {
      \use:x
       {
        \exp_not:N #2
         [ \exp_not:N #1 {\exp_not:V \l_kexx_section_textoa_tl} ]
         [ \exp_not:N #1 {\exp_not:V \l_kexx_section_textob_tl} ]
         { \exp_not:N #1 {\exp_not:V \l_kexx_section_textm_tl} }
       }
     }
     {
      \IfValueTF{#4}
       {
        \use:x
         {
          \exp_not:N #2
           [ \exp_not:N #1 {\exp_not:V \l_kexx_section_textoa_tl} ]
           { \exp_not:N #1 {\exp_not:V \l_kexx_section_textm_tl} }
         }
       }
       {
        \use:x
         {
          \exp_not:N #2 { \exp_not:N #1 {\exp_not:V \l_kexx_section_textm_tl} }
         }
       }
     }
   }
 }

\tl_new:N \l_kexx_section_textm_tl
\tl_new:N \l_kexx_section_texto_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \kexx_section_keyword:Nn
 {
  \tl_set:Nn #1 { #2 }
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { (\<.*?\>) } { \c{textttnocase}\cB\{\1\cE\} } #1
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewDocumentCommand{\redtext}{m}{\textcolor{red}{#1}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\textttnocase}{m}{\NoCaseChange{\texttt{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Headline <keyword>}

\section{Headline <keyword> \redtext{\itshape{this}}}

\subsection{Headline  <keyword>}

\subsection[<key>][aaa<key>]{Headline\"a \redtext{<keyword>}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that page headers need special treatment, too.

Comment: This is a good solution, is it possible to make the text (not `<keyword>`) in a subsection uppercase?

Comment: Yes please, it's only the subsection.

Comment: @kexxcream added

Comment: For some reason, that distorted current headlines. Using your first option with `latexsection` and `latexsubsection` kept things as they are. Is it possible to integrate these instead of `memoir`?

Comment: @kexxcream Sorry: I'm not clairvoyant. You have to also change the page style to *not* use uppercasing. You aren't giving enough information.

Comment: I take it back, forgot to deactivate current styling. Quite a miss. Your solution works well. Thank you kindly! Do you by any chance offer an online class in LaTex or know one that is useful to learn regex?

Comment: @kexxcream Look for `l3regex` on the site, there are several examples.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                                   {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                   {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                                   {\normalfont\Large\bfseries\zz}}
\renewcommand\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}%
                                     {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                     {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
                                     {\normalfont\large\bfseries\zz}}
\def\zz#1{\makeatletter\catcode`\<\active\scantokens{#1}}
{\catcode`\<\active\gdef<#1>{\texttt{#1}}}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Headline <keyword> \textcolor{red}{\itshape{this}}}

zzzzzz

\subsection{Headline  <keyword>}

zzzzzz

\end{document}
```

---

the fragment added to the question appears to be from `memoir` so here's the same but added to memoir rather than article

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{color}
\makeatletter
\protected\def\colsection{green}
\protected\def\colsubsection{blue}
\protected\def\colzz{red}
%
\setsecindent{0pt}
\setbeforesecskip{-8mm plus -1mm minus -1mm}
\setaftersecskip{1.411mm plus 0.2mm minus 0.2mm}
\setsecnumformat{\csname the#1\endcsname\hspace*{0.5em}}
\setsecheadstyle{\rmfamily\mdseries\fontsize{14}{14}\selectfont\raggedright\color{\colsection}\zz}
%
\setsubsecindent{0pt}
\setbeforesubsecskip{-24pt plus -3pt minus -2pt}
\setaftersubsecskip{4pt plus 0pt}
\setsubsecheadstyle{\sffamily\bfseries\boldmath\fontsize{9.5}{14}\selectfont\raggedright\color{\colsubsection}\zzz}
%

\protected\def\zz#1{\makeatletter\catcode`\<\active\scantokens{#1}}
\protected\def\zzz#1{\makeatletter\catcode`\<\active \scantokens{\MakeUppercase{#1}}}
{\catcode`\<\active\protected\gdef<#1>{\texttt{\string <#1>}}}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Headline <keyword> \textcolor{\colzz}{\itshape{this}}}

zzzzzz

\subsection{Headline  <keyword>}

zzzzzz

\end{document}
```

Comment: Cheers @David, however if I want to make sure that `<` and `>` follows with the formatting, what would I need to change?

Comment: @kexxcream sorry I don't understand the comment

Comment: My apologies for not being clear. I would like the output to include `<` and `>` around the keyword. Would it also be possible to not break the text formatting?

Comment: @kexxcream oh `\texttt{\string<#1>}` in that case

Comment: Thanks, but it seems to me that existing formatting for `section` and `subsection` breaks, is there a way around this? Sorry for not stating this already in my original post.

Comment: @kexxcream it should do, but of course you didn't supply a test file in your question....

Comment: Correct, I am using a class that is provided to me which formats section and subsection. It's quite long to paste and for that reason, I made the decision not to include it. However, I should have mentioned earlier that the formatting should not break. Sorry for that.

Comment: @kexxcream the code above should not break any formatting that is in the heading. but if you are using a heading that is using some non standard definition then of course anything is possible but I can't guess what it is doing if you don't show, sorry.

Comment: @kexxcream I updated the example with colour and font changes in the heading.

Comment: Made an update in the original post, managed to figure out the code for section headings. It's the `\normalfont\Large\bfseries` that is affecting existing formatting.

Comment: @kexxcream well yes i copied the definitions from article.cls and added the `<>` code, I thought it was clear that for other classes you'd need to start from whatever that class was doing

Comment: I should perhaps ask if there is an alternative to the proposed solution that would not directly affect the formatting of the `\section` and `\subsection` commands?

Comment: @kexxcream I added a memoir version to match your code fragment

Comment: Truly beautiful, you made my evening.

Comment: Is it possible to only make the text and not `<element>` in uppercase? Right now it's `HEADLINE <KEYWORD>` but I wonder if it is possible to make it `HEADLINE <keyword>`?