# Split a string based on keyword and delimiters

Tags: pdftex, color, delimiters, keywords, split

**Problem:**

I have two words that I would like to split into two variables. For instance:

Word 1 [Word 2]

**Minimal Working Example:**

I have not been able to generate a minimal working example as I have not been able to find anything similar to this issue, either on Google or SO. The specific issue with this problem is the delimiters `[`and `]`.

**Desired output:**

Based on the delimiters `[`and `]`, the output should enable formatting either word in its own way. I have looked into `xparse` package but could not manage to figure out how to tackle the delimiter issue.

**For instance:**

Word 1 could be coloured in blue

[Word 2] could be coloured in red (braces to be included in output).

Comment: Do you want a macro to produce such colored output? A macro with optional argument?

Comment: your question is very unclear. do you mean that the input always is of the form `xxx[yyy]` and you always split before the `[` ?

Comment: @Sigur Yes to both, sorry for not stating that.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, it will always be `Word 1 [Word 2]`. The split always occur before `[`.

Comment: So `[Word 2]` is not optional.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\zz#1{\zzz#1}
\def\zzz#1[#2]{\textcolor{blue}{#1}\textcolor{red}{[#2]}}

\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}

\zz{Word 1 [Word 2]}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Beat me by a minute, though I just went with the `\zzz` definition, to avoid the need for braces.

Comment: Thanks, but the `[` and `]` should be included in the output. I have updated my post.

Comment: @kexxcream updated answer

Comment: Now update your image, and eliminate the extra space before the red `\textcolor`

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes give me a second (well, 19, it seems!)

Comment: What?? Only two hands?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks, this worked out well, much appreciated! Can I kindly ask you to look into an older issue you helped me with before? It's available here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/360671/format-keywords-inside-section-and-subsection/.